# googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: HttpError 404

Tags: python, gmail, google-api-client, google-directory-api

I have imported google library

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError, Error
```

and this is my code

```
response = service.users().get(userKey=email).execute()

user_id=(response['id'])
try:
    if user_id:
        return True
# except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
    print(e)
```

but it is still not catching that exception.

Here is the error

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/cccc%404domain`enter code here`.com?alt=json returned "Resource Not Found: userKey". Details: "Resource Not Found: userKey">
```

purpose of my code is to check if that email already exists.
If email exists it prints the email address but if email dose not exist it gives this error message above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem today.

Found the issue to be that the error is raising where you have .execute currently.

Try this library

```
from googleapiclient import errors
```

Try putting execute into a while or if statement

```
response = service.users().get(userKey=email)

if response is not None:
    try:
        r = response.execute()
        user_email = r.get('primaryEmail', [])
        print(user_email)

    except errors.HttpError:
        print('Not found')
```